# In bash what does if [ "$VAR" ] mean

Tags: bash

I understand how the if function works in bash, but the problem is that I don't get what it means if you aren't comparing it with something. I know there are a bunch of switches like -e or -c or -f, but when would the following code get evaluated as true?

```
if [ "$VAR" ]; then
  echo "TRUE"
else
  echo "FALSE"
fi
```

I'm trying to interpret a script someone wrote for me.

Comment: `if` is a statement, not a function. Also, you question is concerning the `test` command (spelled `[` here), not the `if` statement itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `help test`:

```
     STRING      True if string is not empty.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the following:

```
-n STRING
       the length of STRING is nonzero
STRING equivalent to -n STRING
```

Just the test for non-empty value.